# PIXI JS - How to update mesh UVs?

Tags: typescript, opengl-es, mesh, pixi.js

I want to know how to update mesh UVs.

The UVs seem to be applied well when init.
But if this modifies dynamically, the UVs do not reflect it.
Is this a bug in PIXI JS? Or my fault?

```
...
uvs: Float32Array = new Float32Array([ 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 ]);
mesh: PIXI.mesh.Mesh = new PIXI.mesh.Mesh(texture, vertices, uvs, indices);
```

in runtime

```
this.mesh.uvs[2] += this.offset;
this.mesh.uvs[4] += this.offset;
```

not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that PixiJS makes available to you is on the CPU, but the mesh rendered by the GPU uses data in the GPU.

You only updated the CPU data, to make it available to the GPU, you must increment YourMesh.dirty so PixiJS knows that the data has changed and that he needs to update the GPU data.

you should have something like this:

```
this.mesh.uvs[2] += this.offset;
this.mesh.uvs[4] += this.offset;
this.mesh.dirty ++;
```